# how to prevent C++ variable from being optimized out

Tags: c++, c, optimization, g++

I have seen a lot of other questions asking this same thing and every single one suggests declaring the variable every possible combination of `static volatile` or turning off optimizations using `#pragma` or `__attribute__`. In my case, I am not using any optimization flags during compilation and using `volatile` is not possible since the value is passed to functions of other libraries that do not use `volatile` and casting it away is not allowed (throws compiler error, for good reason).

So I am looking for an alternative solution to this problem. Why do I want to do this? I think like most other people asking this question I am trying to inspect some code with gdb and the value I am interested in is being optimized out.

One thought I have is that there may be a standard C/C++ function I could call that would prevent the optimization from taking place. Unfortunately I don't know enough about how values are optimized out to know what functions might do this.

NOTE: I say C/C++ because I am compiling with C++ but am wrapping some of my code in `extern "C"` blocks. In particular, my `main` is C++ and I am using some shared libraries of which 2 are compile as C and the other is compiled as C++ with `extern "C"` blocks.

Comment: Just compile with `-O0`, and turn on debugging symbols with `-g` or `-ggdb3`.

Comment: Debug your code without optimization.

Comment: @cigien, @TonyTannous as I said in my post I am not using any optimization flags. gcc defaults to `-O0` but I went ahead and tryed compiling with it just in case and had no change. For completeness, here are all the compiler flags I am using: `-std=c++11 -fPIC -O0  -g -Wall -Og

Comment: Then you'll need to print out the values of the variables.

Comment: @jdodle: `-Og` on the command line overrides `-O0` -- you need to use `-O0` AND NO OTHER -O options